# What function/code can I use to remove all rows that are blank?

Tags: r

Im looking to add a line of code that looks for blanks or NA’s in column 9 and then removes those rows in their entirety. Below I will detail the code that is currently working. I’m using “etc.” for non important information and to shorten it. For awareness, I’m loading a .xlsx in R-studio to work with. Any ideas would be highly appreciative. Thanks all.

```
Library(openxlsx)
Library(dplyr)
Library(lubridate)
Library(tidyverse)

setwd(“c:/users “etc.”)
wb <- loadworkbook (“etc”)
Worksheet <- sheets (wb)
detectdates = TRUE

SetColWidths(wb, worksheet, cols=
c(“etc.”), widths= c(“etc.”))

##WOULD LIKE TO ADD CODE HERE##

setwd(“C:/users “etc.”)
saveworkbook (wb,
paste0(“etc.”),overwrite=TRUE
```

Comment: Perhaps `tidyr::drop_na(data, col9)` where `col9` is the name of column 9, and `data` is a dataframe of your data could work? It's difficult to know without knowing what your data looks like. If you add a reproducible example, it'll be much easier to help.

Comment: Package openxlsx is mainliy for formatting applications. You should read the data into a dataframe first, with df <- read.xlsx(path) then use tidyr as indicated by nrennie, then save the file with write.xlsx(df, path)

Comment: `which(rowSums == 0)`  and work with that

Comment: It appears based on the feedback listed above that I’m trying to do two different sets things with one script which may be the problem. For example, SetColWidths is a formatting function and works by calling a workbook, but if I wanted to do data cleaning tasks (aka remove blanks) I may want to write a separate script using a data frame. SetColWidths doesn’t work with the dataframe. Is it possible to do all this in one script or is it not recommended? I’m running into problems with calling the workbook/dataframe into different functions unfortunately. @Ric

Comment: I'm not an user of openxlm library but i guess you can read  data.frame's with write.xls and read.xlsx function provided by the package, do the data manipulation, save with write.xlsx, then loadworkbook and do the styling

Comment: Okay - I found the full open.xlsx pdf guide. It is 130+ pages. I’ll try to use control+f and apply the functions to a new script and see if it works better for my needs. Thanks. @Ric